# How to find an internship place in a different city than my university is?

Tags: masters, job-search, germany, internship, masters-post-phd

Long story short: I moved to Germany to do a Msc in molecular biology. Since corona, all my lectures and exams are online. Because of financial reasons, I decided to move to a different city (Berlin). But I have 2 internships to complete.... one is for about 5 weeks and the other is for 10 weeks (for my thesis). They should be at the same place.
But I don't have connections here. I tried to cold-email professors, but some of them don't answer, another ones simply don't have time because of corona. I tried to get some advice from my home university, but ofc they can't help me (apart from advising cold emailing :D )
How could I approach research groups? I am kinda lost in this situation. My last option is to move back to my home university, only for the internship, but it would be very costly and I don't want to do that.

Comment: How far is your home university (in case you don't want to specify)? Do they have connections to research institutes, organizations, etc.? You could try to find profs at your home uni who know you and know someone around Berlin.  And finally, why would you move to Berlin for *financial* reasons? There's far cheaper places.

Comment: Other than that: Try to make your emails cold-emailing people look more approachable than your post. (Sorry if this sounds rude, but I think this is good advice. This is quite a wall of text.)

Comment: How much time do you have before you would need to begin the internships? (and are the internships purely academic?) That might be important to determine if you should try and get known by people at universities in Berlin before cold-emailing. Furthermore do you have anyone who you've worked with before that might be able to vouch for you and your abilities?

Comment: @user151413   hi! I moved to Berlin, because one of my relatives live here, so I don't have to pay for the accomodation. So because of this, it is cheaper for me. My home university is approximately 4-4,5 hours from Berlin. Train is quite costly, btw.
I have tried to ask professors about it. But it is not easy- I don't know any of them in person.

Comment: @NAMcMahon  I have about 4 months to start an internship. An academic internship is easier to get accepted in my home university, than one in the industry. I think it is a good idea to get to know people at universities in Berlin, but still, how? 
Btw, I have people that could reference my previous work, yes.

Comment: Why don't you do your internships at your university and rent a small apartment for those 5+10 weeks (with the current situation, Airbnb etc. should be easily available)? Given you don't pay rent now, this is likely still significantly cheaper than having lived in the place of your university for the whole time.

Comment: @user151413 That is an option. But actually, that also costs money and all in all it would be much more confortable to find a place here. (Also, I want to go to phd in Berlin, so it would be a good starting point to find a group because of that. I will keep trying to get an internship place before the end of February, and if I don't succeed then I will move back for a short time.

Comment: But didn't you plan to do all of your studies in the other city, which would have cost even more money? So you're still better off.  If you want to save that money, you'll work hard to find someone to host you.  Keep contacting people, and do it in a way which catches their attention (brief and addressee-specific).